# Create a loop in Python to find any entry from one list in another list

Tags: python, list, append

Is there a way to append only those entries of my `help_list` to the `final_list`, that include either one of the `keywords` **and** either one of the `magazine_names`?

```
help_list = ["aa mag1", "aa mag2", "aa mag3", "bb mag4", "aa mag4", "bb mag2", "aa mag3", "cc mag1", "aa mag4", "ii mag4"]

keywords = ["aa", "ii"]
magazine_names = ["mag3", "mag4"]

final_list = []

for entry in help_list:    
    if any(element in help_list for element in keywords) and any(element in help_list for element in magazine_names):
        final_list.append(entry)

print(final_list)
```

As a side note: For my actual code, the list with the keywords and the list with the magazines include over 100 entries each.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: yes there is a way infact there are several ways

Comment: Edited the original post with my latest approach (that failed).

Comment: Are the keywords and magazines making a pair? like you say that it must have one from keyworks and one from magazine. your help list looks like a list of strings which are formed as keyword then space then magazine? is that correct. if so you can build a list of key/mag pairs with itertools product then just check against that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```py
def contains_one(item, search_terms):
    """Returns true iff any item of `search_terms` is contained in item.
    """
    for search in search_terms:
        if search in item:
            return True
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    help_list = ["aa mag1", "aa mag2", "aa mag3", "bb mag4", "aa mag4", "bb mag2", "aa mag3", "cc mag1", "aa mag4", "ii mag4"]

    keywords = ["aa", "ii"]
    magazine_names = ["mag3", "mag4"]

    final_list = []

    for item in help_list:
        if contains_one(item, keywords) and contains_one(item, magazine_names):
            final_list.append(item)

    print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```python
k_set = set(keywords)
m_set = set(magazine_names)
final_list = [h for h in help_list if h.split()[0] in k_set and h.split()[1] in m_set]
```